# Various coroutine filtering operations with return value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have situation where I have list of items. I want to to 3 changes on them.
On my initial list, I want to do change 1. I need to wait till this finishes and than after that happens, on my newList I want to do change2. Again I need to wait till operation2 finished and after that I want to do change3. Now I would get my finalList.

I want to do calculations/changes with coroutines and return value after all this happens.
I will write pseudocode to show you what I mean. However, my code does have errors and it does not compile. Please help:

```
    Class Operator()
{    
    val startingList: List<String>
    

    fun doListOperations(){
       

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

    
    
     async{doOperation1}.await
     async{doOperation2}.await
     async{doOperation3}.await
    }
    
  
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                   return@withContext startingList
                }
    
   
    
    
    }

 fun doOperation1(){
    //DOES SOME OPERATIONS ON startingList. Same applies on doOperation2 and doOperation3
    }
   
}
tried the code above but need some good good example how to solve this
```

Comment: What is the point of launching an asynchronous operation if you actually need to wait for it? Just invoke all operations directly, without `async()`.

Comment: @broot Ok so you mean to do all this in CoroutineScope launch, without async. Are the opeartions gonna be dona sequentialy (doOperation2 must not start before doOperation1 is finished). 
Also how to return value in this case

Comment: Yes, they will be invoked sequentially. Also, where do you want to return the result to? You launch()'ed the whole operation, so nobody is really waiting for any result. If you need to do something after the last operation, put it also below: `doOperation1(); doOperation2(); doOperation3(); doSomethingWithResult();`.

Comment: @broot I want to return this list after all operations. My other class calls this helper class to do operations. So my doListOperations() function returns List<String>. After the doOperation3() I want to return list. I can not edit code bcs I am new contributor :/

Comment: Well, right now `doListOperations()` is fully asynchronous. That means it only schedules operations in the background and returns immediately, long before operations finish. So there is really now way to return results from this directly. The best solution using coroutines would be to make `doListOperations()` suspend, remove `launch()` and simply return from it as from any other function. Alternatively, you can provide result asynchronously using callbacks, futures, etc., but coroutines were designed specifically as a replacement for such patterns.

Comment: @broot I understand, but if I make doListOperations() suspend and remove launch, how can I achieve that my code runs sequentialy. if I call doOperation1(); doOperation2(); doOperation3(); it will start excuting all of them at once..? 
Or my suspend function knows I call it with launch{} in other class so it still executes functions one by one..?

Comment: Why do you expect any code to not work sequentially in the first place? Code in almost any language in the world is sequential by default. `val y = x + 2; val z = y * 5;` doesn't compute `y` and `z` concurrently, but sequentially. Similarly, `doOperation1(); doOperation2();` is by default sequential. To run operations concurrently we have to ask for it explicitly, for example by using `launch()` or `async()`. Of course, this is true as long as your `doOperationX()` functions don't launch any background operations by themselves. If they do, then they really shouldn't and you need to fix them.

Comment: @broot ok got it. I implemented all as you said and works like charm! I have one last question. Why does doListOperations() should be suspend fun? When I implement like this, it says that suspend is redundant modifier. That it can be safe deleted. And after I delete suspend, your code still works. So why do I need it..?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it doesn't have to be suspend. Initially, I assumed individual operations are suspend and this is why you use coroutines here. But then I realized they are regular functions, so `doListOperations()` doesn't have to be or even shouldn't be suspend as well.

Comment: @broot that was great talk. Thank you very much man you really helped me with this <3